# Spock GlobalExtension is not loaded (grails)

Tags: grails, spock, geb

I want to register a Listener to all spock geb specs in my grails-app so I added a IGlobalExtension to *myapp/src/groovy*

```
package myapp.spock

class TakeScreenshotExtension implements IGlobalExtension {
    @Override
    void visitSpec(SpecInfo specInfo) {
        System.err.println "ADDING LISTENER"
        specInfo.addListener(new TakeScreenshotOnFailureListener())
    }
}
```

Afterwards I added the *org.spockframework.runtime.extension.IGlobalExtension* file to *myapp/src/resources/META-INF/services* containing the line

```
myapp.spock.TakeScreenshotExtension
```

So now from what I understood, when running *grails test-app functional:*, the Extension should be loaded but I don't see the "ADDING LISTENER" anywhere in the output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: shouldn't it be System.err.println("ADDING LISTENER") ?

Comment: in Java, you need the braces, in Groovy, you don't...

Answer (score 3):

the right location for the `IGlobalExtension` file seems to be
`grails-app/conf/META-INF/services`, but then I get a `class not found Exception` because spock can't load my extension class. Any Idea where I have to put that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is the exact classpath setup when running functional tests but I would suspect that `myapp/src/resources/META-INF/services/org.spockframework.runtime.extension.IGlobalExtension` might not get added to the test classpath and thus Spock doesn't know about your extension. I would try moving that file under `myapp/test/functional/META-INF/services/org.spockframework.runtime.extension.IGlobalExtension` together moving the extension class under `myapp/test/functional` as well.

Comment: moving that file under myapp/test/functional/META-INF/services/org.spockframework.runtime.extension.IGlobalExtension together moving the extension class under myapp/test/functional as well. --> I tried this but this didnt work any inputs or suggestions